# why my lcd displays like out of signal

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, external-display

My external monitor appears like in image on random time, I have to power off the monitor and on again to get working. It is making me crazy.

[image]

I am using:

- Macbook pro 2012 model
- external monitor (SAMSUNG SyncMaster P2250) using DVI cable with mini display port.

Comment: When did it start?  Does it happen when certain things occur?  Have you tried a different cable?  How old is the monitor?

Comment: Have you tried just reconnecting the cable? It occured sometimes with my Macbook too.

Comment: I am getting this for 6 months approx, and it just occur randomly. I had tried with different cable, but happening same. Monitor is nearly 2 years old. Yes I had tried with reconnecting cable, it works for few time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not exact answer for my own question, but my problem got solved , may you guys have better explanation,

I was using monitor with powered by UPS, and when I moved this monitor to my friends home, problem is not happening again.

seems, is there problem with electricity source ?